# How can i tag the x largest numbers in a query

Tags: mysql

Given the following simple table:

```
Value
10
4
7
2
4
6
```

How do i write a **select query** that **tags** the x biggest values. For example below the desired query output if the 3 biggest values are tagged.

```
Value   IsBiggest
10      true
4       false
7       true
2       false
4       false
6       true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way:

```
(select value, 'true' as IsBiggest from simple_table order by value desc limit 3)
union all
(select value, 'false' as IsBiggest from simple_table order by value desc limit 3, 9223372036854775807)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT test.value, 
       CASE WHEN X.isBiggest IS NULL THEN false ELSE true END isBiggest
FROM test 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT value, true isBiggest
        FROM test 
        ORDER BY value DESC
        LIMIT 0,3
    ) X ON
    test.value = X.value
```

IF you only what the top 3:

```
SELECT value
FROM test 
ORDER BY value DESC
LIMIT 0,3
```

Comment: Your solution worked just fine, however Oto Shavadze solution was slightly faster in my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
SELECT tb1.value , IF(tb2.isBiggest ,1, 0) AS isBiggest FROM `sample_table` tb1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT value , 1 AS isBiggest
FROM  `sample_table` 
ORDER BY value DESC 
LIMIT 3
) tb2 ON tb1.value = tb2.value
```

Answer (score -1):

You could sort values and than tag X first items:
Example in Oracle:

```
WITH tab AS (
SELECT 10 AS VALUE FROM dual 
UNION SELECT 4 AS VALUE FROM dual
UNION SELECT 7 AS VALUE FROM dual
UNION SELECT 2 AS VALUE FROM dual
UNION SELECT 4 AS VALUE FROM dual
UNION SELECT 6 AS VALUE FROM dual
)
SELECT VALUE, CASE WHEN ROWNUM <=3 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS IsBigest FROM (SELECT VALUE FROM tab ORDER BY VALUE DESC);
```

output:

```
10  true
7   true
6   true
4   false
2   false
```

Comment: downvoted MySQL doesnt support window functions like WITH AS

Answer (score -1):

For the 3 highest values tagged you should try :

```
select top (3) Value from my_table
order by Value desc
```